# Visible cells row count calculates as very low even there are more rows showing after filtering

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet where Im doing some filtering. After filtering according to excel status bar 95 filtered from 10000+ records and we can obviously see the 95 records only visible in the filtered list. But when I try to take the number of visible rows or filtered rows using this code following, it returns a very low value (Only 22). Didnt understand why its so low.

Here is the code

```
With Sheets("FullInvoice").Range("A1:N" & lRow)
    .Cells(1, 1).Select
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & fD, Criteria2:="<=" & lD
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=selectedSOW, Criteria2:="<>0"
    '.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd
    'Set xRange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With
rCount = Range("A2:N" & Sheets("FullInvoice").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.count
```

Here after all the autofilter there is clearly 95 rows. But in rCount only returns 22.. Didnt understand why

If we simply include this line of code

```
Range("A2:A10409").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).select
```

its clearly selecting 95 rows. Even then when we try

```
Range("A2:A10409").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).rows.count
```

it says **22**. Really got stucked

Comment: Dont count rows, count cells of one column `rCount = Range("A2:N" & Sheets("FullInvoice").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns("A").Cells.Count`

Comment: You're building your filter on `Sheets("FullInvoice").Range("A1:N" & lRow)` but you're counting rows based upon `Range("A2:N" & Sheets("FullInvoice").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)` - I'd suggest choosing one of these for both.

Comment: @CLR He doesn't need to count headers, `lRow` (I hope I'm not mistaken) is basicly the same as `Sheets("FullInvoice").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` so this part of code is out of the question.

Comment: @AntiDrondert That is also 22

Comment: My comment was based on a guess that the filter is not extending fully down the data, which would make sense if the two row counts were different. Hence if you stick to one or the other, you are *more likely* (it is just a guess - we can't see the sheet) to get the same row count

Comment: @CLR The lRow is taking the full used range and its 10020 which is correct according to used range.. So for a try when we do a select on that range, its selects the whole rows. So the filter is being applied to the full rows.

Comment: In that case it may help if you include the piece of code that sets `lRow`. If that is the case though, why don't you use `lRow` in your `rCount` line instead of finding the `xlUp` row value?

Comment: @CLR That is 100% true. I changed it to lRow. But still its sticked with the 22

Comment: There are 22 rows in the first **Area**.

Comment: @SandeepThomas Try looping through **Areas** as in `Dim rngArea As Range : For Each rngArea In Range("A2:N" & Sheets("FullInvoice").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas : rCount = rCount + rngArea.Rows.Count : Next`

Comment: @AntiDrondert Yea.. that is something I guess as a solution too... since its keeps weird value.. Thanks

Comment: and if N has the same number of rows as F you get the expected result I think.

Comment: @SandeepThomas It realy IS weird, because "count cells instead of rows" solution worked fine for me in the past. Anyway, looping through areas might be slower but at least it is reliable.